# Do methods are transformed into delegates?

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

My understanding of delegates is that delegate is a special object that containts sequence of pointers to methods (each method should have the same return type and parameters).

Lets consider that we defined delegate like that

```
delegate int MyDelegate(string name, int age);
```

We can use it later in code like that

```
// creating the instance of delegate
MyDelegate objDelegate = null;

// initialising that instance
objDelegate += (string name, int age) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Anonymous method is starting to work");
    return age + 2;
};

// execution of some method whith delegate as last parameter
objProgram.PrintBaseInfo("example", -2, objDelegate);
```

**But why I can pass methods WITHOUT creating a delegate for them?**

```
objProgram.PrintBaseInfo("Alexandr", 23, anotherClass.MyMethod);
```

In the example above i'm just passing method of some class (not delegate). My assumption is that compiler creates delegate for it and initializes it with this method, but i'm not sure.

PS Just to remove misunderstanding of question, here is definiton of PrintBaseInfo:

```
public void PrintBaseInfo(string name, int age, MyDelegate InnerFunc){some code}
```

Comment: But if the method conforms to the specification, what's the difference? You don't *create a delegate*; it's like "a delegate is to a particular method what a class is to an object instance". A delegate is a specification, and a method is an implementation that conforms to the spec. A class is a specification and an object instance is a bunch of data that conforms to the spec

Comment: My main misunderstanding is that I can't get the difference between instance of delegate and methods. Yes, delegate is like class for methods, from listing in top MyDelegate is definiton of that "class" and objDelegate is instance of that class. But objDelegate can contain SEVERAL references to the methods, so it's like container for references to the methods, and because of that I think that when method wants to get a delegate it wants to get that container, not some one ref. So I assume that compiler will transform reference to anotherClass.MyMethod to that container during the compilation.

Comment: By "transform to container" I mean it will create container (instance of  MyDelegate), initialize that container with reference to the given method (anotherClass.MyMethod) and  only then it will pass it for the method that requires delegate as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, compiler will create delegate for you.

[TryRoslyn](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDKgZgASwwZQPYC2ApgMIA2AhgM5XIDeyGTWmUALBgCoUDWRVUODAAUgmBgoBjAC4BLPADsAlI2YMkzDAF9kqpuiwcSFMmSrc+AocJUa1ezV178xwgLJFpACzzAAchTESgDcDjoodvqscABshhge3r4BxDYO6prhWkA=)

```
using System;

public class SomeClass
{
    public void TakesAction(Action action)
    {
    }

    public void CallsTakesAction()
    {
        TakesAction(MethodName);
    }

    public static void MethodName()
    {
    }
}
```

Is compiled to:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows = true)]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue)]
[assembly: SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.RequestMinimum, SkipVerification = true)]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.0.0.0")]
[module: UnverifiableCode]
public class SomeClass
{
    public void TakesAction(Action action)
    {
    }

    public void CallsTakesAction()
    {
        TakesAction(new Action(MethodName));
    }

    public static void MethodName()
    {
    }
}
```